# Ubuntu: ThinkPad P50 with Docking Station - Flickering Screen on Notebook and external monitors

Tags: drivers, thinkpad

I have recently bought a new Docking Station for my ThinkPad P50. Since yesterday I haven't been able to connect one or two external monitors through the docking station. I have connected one monitor via VGA-Cable and the other one is connected via DVI-Cable.

As I dock on my notebook on the docking station the external monitors and the notebook monitor is every time flickering. If i undock the notebook the computer get the same 'display configuration' as before. Only one error message is shown:

**Could not switch the monitor configuration - could not set the configuration for CRTC 617**

What does this mean?

If i connect one monitor without the docking station it is going to work without trouble with nivida-prime.

What can I do to use my docking station?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal solution (up to now) is to use a minidisplay-adapter for my external monitor in addition to the dock. (I agree, that's not really a solution)

Maybe this helps:
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=241884

and here is a bugrepport reflecting the issue
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-361/+bug/1615734